# How to use two Date picker popoer in same view for two button actions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, binding, datepicker, popover

In my application, I need to show two date pickers  as two different button actions

1. To choose delivery date: When clicking a  button, I need to to show date picker
2. to choose delivery time, When clicking another button , show picker to choose the time

   ```
    struct SwiftUIView: View {
       @State private var showDatePicker = false
       @State private var deliveryDate = Date()
       @State private var showTimePicker = false
       @State private var deliveryTime = Date()

       var body : some View{

                               VStack(spacing:15){
                                   //delivery date
                                   Button {
                                       showDatePicker = true
                                   } label: {
                                       HStack{
                                           Text("Delivery Date")
                                           Spacer()
                                           Image(systemName: "calendar")
                                       }
                                           .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                                   }.padding()
                                       .background {
                                           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                                       }

                                   //delivery time
                                   Button {
                                       showTimePicker = true
                                   } label: {
                                       HStack{
                                           Text("Delivery Time")
                                           Spacer()
                                           Image(systemName: "clock")
                                       }
                                           .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                                   }.padding()
                                       .background {
                                           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
                                       }

                       }
                               .padding()
       .popover(isPresented: $showDatePicker) {
                          DatePopover(components: [.date], dateIn: $deliveryDate, isShowing: $showDatePicker)
                       .onDisappear(){
                           showDatePicker = false
                       }
                       }

       }
   ```

   }

   //Datepicker

   ```
    struct DatePopover: View {
    var components : DatePickerComponents
    @Binding var dateIn: Date
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                DatePicker("", selection: $dateIn, in: Date.now..., displayedComponents: components)
                    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)

                    .onChange(of: dateIn, perform: { value in

                        isShowing.toggle()
                    })
                .padding(.all, 20)
            }.frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        }

    }
   ```

The above code shows the first date picker. How can show a picker again when tapping the second button.

Comment: Why not just using 2 `DatePicker` with 2 var `dateIn` and `dateOut`?

Comment: Two date pickers are not showing at same time. My doubt is, how to handle the popver present modifier. Is that possible